# catkin metapackage now requires CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated my ROS installation today and now `catkin_make` is spitting warnings for my metapackages:

```
-- ~~  - ycs_msgs (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'ycs_msgs' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /opt/yujin/ycs/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/ycs_msgs/CMakeLists.txt
```

The two things I wonder about now are:

- The warning tells me to add a CMakeLists.txt to my metapackages, while the instructions on the [catkin wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages) tells me different:

> Metapackages do not require a CMakeLists.txt file. If one is provided, it is ignored by catkin.

- The proposed CMakeLists.txt contains the new macro call `catkin_metapackage()`. Is there any information about this functionality out there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59648/catkin-metapackage-now-requires-cmakelists.txt?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-31**:
I had an old CmakeLists.txt (created by catkin_create_pkg) in one metapackage which caused the build to break, since they are not ignored anymore. Those old lists make catkin think these metapackages are non-catkin packages. Might be worth to send out a warning on ros-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was discussed on the ros-buildsystem sig as well as in the ROS platform group meetings, and subsequently added to [REP-127](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#metapackage) as shown in the history [here on github](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/commit/33b60d566324c66f5ad03946116020c062a53991) on March 7th.

I'm really surprised this change was released into groovy. I thought it wasn't going to take effect until Hydro.

**From [REP-127](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#metapackage) as it reads today:**

> The empty tag is used to indicate that a package is a metapackage which implies that it does only have a fixed minimal CMakeLists.txt which will only install the package.xml file. This information is necessary for the ROS wiki to show the relationship between these metapackages and other packages and as a backward compatibility with rosbuild. Non-metapackages must not depend on metapackages but instead on the packages they depend on.

> The CMakeLists.txt file for a metapackage is supposed to look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(PACKAGE_NAME)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
catkin_metapackage()
```

**From the [buildsystem sig mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ros-sig-buildsystem/mn-VCkl2OHk/dUsHBBjyK30J) (@tkruse):**

> So the currently favoured solution will be to allow CMakeLists.txt with metapackages. In order to encourage users to not fill their metapackages with anything else than just the installation of the package manifest itself, catkin will scan the CmakeLists.txt and warn if users put in more than the minimally required lines. This may still change if someone has a better idea, or other blockers appear.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-01**:
+1 to making these changes only in Hydro, not in Groovy. Where do I open a defect issue for that?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-04-01**:
Haha, everywhere? Probably worth emailing the buildsystem sig, adding an issue on the catkin github project, a pull request on the rep project, and sending a singing telegram to Dirk's home...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The precipitation of this change was well covered by @jbohren

We are currently in the process of rolling out this change, unfortunately `catkin` hitting the public repositories was the first thing that had to happen, and it happened on a weekend.

I have just updated the wiki:

http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages

I am going to release `bloom` 0.3.3 (which also has changes related to this), republish the REP pages, regenerate the `catkin` documentation, and then send an email about the change.

As for why this is in `groovy`? It is not an API breaking change, it does nothing more than warn you if you are building a non compliant metapackage locally. The only case where it breaks is if you have a random `CMakeLists.txt` wandering around in the root of your metapackages, which is not correct anyways. On the flip side, releasing it into `groovy` prevents us from having yet further special case handling in tools like `catkin_pkg` and `bloom`.

As for documentation of `catkin_metapackage`, it is self documented:

https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/groovy-devel/cmake/catkin_metapackage.cmake#L1

And those docs will be in the generated documentation for `catkin`, which will also be regenerated today as we roll this out.

**UPDATE:**

- catkin's RST docs have been updated and will be regenerated tonight (this happens nightly)
- bloom 0.3.3 has been released
- hosted REP pages have been updated
- email has been sent

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-04-01**:
Where did this email go to? IMO significant changes to the core parts of ROS should be announced **visibly**, that is ros-users, and **prior** to their release. Then people will know what work is linked to the next update.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-04-01**:
Looks like I commented too early. Just received your email on ros-users. Thanks!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-01**:
ros-users, I got a bounce (new email) which went to my spam folder, it should go out soon.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-01**:
We'll try to do better next time about features before releasing, I cannot speak for the rest of the team, but I think this didn't show up as a significant change as it shouldn't have impacted users other than the warning. In Hydro, for instance, it is required and produces an error.